# Can I use USB gamepad without any setup?

Tags: usb, game-controllers

I connected USB gamepad to my tablet.

I noticed that software like Tincore KeyMapper requires root access to connect to this gamepad.
This type of software recognizes all buttons, but asks me to map these buttons to screen areas.

1. Can I use a gamepad without mapping buttons to screen?
2. Do games support this mode?
3. Do I need to download some piece of software that will ask root access for these games?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use a USB game controller without root and without needing any prior setup. Just plug it in and Android will recognise it. By default, the D-pad on the controller will work like a D-pad or trackball on the device itself (if you remember when Android phones used to have little trackballs built in), and it will allow you to move focus between controls in most apps.

Stock apps are completely accessible using the controller without the touch screen, but not all third-party apps are. Many games (especially emulators for games consoles) support using a Bluetooth or USB game controller, but not all games do. The idea of apps like the one you mention is to make button presses on the game controller trigger touch screen events, so if you play a game that has on-screen controls but doesn't support controllers, the controller will trigger the game's on-screen controls. Generally you'll get a better playing experience, as well as easy setup, by choosing a game that supports game controllers.

If you just plug the controller in, it'll work in any supported apps and games right away. Games with controller support usually advertise it in the description on the store, but if you're not sure you can ask the developer through their support email address.

Comment: Actually my gemepad is not recognized and don't work. It's standard XInput device that works in windows without drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I have a miniPC CS968 (RK3188) with Android 4.2.2.

My gamepads (PLayStation 1 and SNES style) work out of the box.

I updated it to Android 4.4.2 and the gamepads no longer work fine. They get recognized partially. Some buttons don't work. I downgraded it to 4.2.2 again and I, luckly, get them working out of the box.

My PlayStation 2 style gamepad works fine with Android 4.4.2. I hope my others gamepads worked too.

Comment: This sounds more like a new question than an answer to this question.

Comment: This is up to the individual app developers to provide support across Android versions

Comment: More like a comment than a new question.  It adds details about models and versions.  Me too have several controllers and just some of them are recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperkin NES style controllers with USB work with my andoid. I use the USB female to Micro Male adapter and Boom! EarthBound ROMs all day baby. Super easy and so many controllers corded work flawlessly. So much less hastle than bluetooth.