# Can I use Tasker to simulate Page Up / Page Down without root access?

Tags: adb, tasker, touchscreen, user-interface

I've read people doing it [using adb](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/167001) without root access. I've also read that people can do it [using Tasker and several other methods, but with root access](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/118917/209129).

Is it possible to do the same with Tasker (or other methods without involving devices other than the phone itself), but without root access? If not, why so?