# How do I run 2 Android phones on a PC simultaneously so that DroidCam on one phone & TC games screen mirror on another phone?

Tags: adb, usb, remote-control, webcam, screen-mirroring

I have 2 Android phones and I want to connect both of them to my PC via USB cables like this:

1. Motorola Moto G3 5.1.1 (Lollipop) goes to the DroidCam app to use as a webcam.
2. Samsung S4 Zoom (KitKat) goes to mirror screen Android to PC app called "TC games" for screen share and controlling my phone from my PC.

Right now, I have Universal ADB Driver installed on PC and I can't run both programs at the same time. This message pops up when I use DroidCam at the same time with Tc games: "adb server is out of date. Killing...".

How can I connect Motorola to DroidCam as a default, and TC games to Samsung and run both of them at the same time without any problem?

Comment: Are you using the Lollipop device for webcam & mic audio or just webcam? If only webcam but no audio on Lollipop, can you swap webcam android and mirror screen android devices so that you can use something like [QTScrcpy](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/224361/3573) so like Robert stated use one `adb` version? Or can't as you are streaming over Skype or something?

Answer (score 0):

Applications like DroidCam or Scrcpy that require adb to work often include an own version of adb. For DroidCam you can see it in the sub-directory `adb` the three files that belong to adb:

- adb.exe
- AdbWinApi.dll
- AdbWinUsbApi.dll

However adb is designed to be present one time on a system because when it starts it remains loaded invisible in the background.

Now if a program has it's own adb version it prefers this versions and therefore when it starts it's own adb version the previous adb daemon running background is killed and replaced with the different adb version.

In your case the message `adb server is out of date.` additionally indicates that you have two different versions of adb installed and the newer version kills the older version that was already running (old version = out of date version).

Some programs like Scrcpy allow to specify via environment variable where `adb.exe` is located so that you can redirect it to one adb versions that is available on your system.
I am not sure if DroidCam also supports such an environment variable.

But in any way you should "equalize" all adb versions you have installed:

1. Search your system where it has `adb.exe` installed
2. On each found `adb.exe` execute `adb.exe --version` and identify the newest version (the version installed with Android Studio shows at the moment `Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41 - Version 30.0.2-6538114`
3. From the newest adb version copy the three files `adb.exe`, `AdbWinApi.dll` and `AdbWinUsbApi.dll` to the other locations `adb.exe` was found overwriting the existing files.

This should at least solve your problem that the adb versions installed have a different version.

Comment: thank you for your answer. the problem is with the old android in s4 zoom it can run only with TC games screen mirror via USB because TC provides older adb:
adb-1-0-32-platform-23-0-1.exe
adb-1-0-40-platform-28-0-2.exe
adb-1-0-41-platform-29-0-6.exe
I've tried so many time connect s4 zoom to iVCam via USB and it did not work, but it has worked via WiFi. and when i copied the 3 adb files from TC folder to iVCam the 2nd did not work correctly via USB with neither 2 phones.