# Trigger the starting of an app remotely

Tags: applications, remote-control, remote-access

I want to initiate the start of an app on (my own) phone. It is not rooted, because practically no android can be rooted today, but I can install anything to it or change any setting on it. I also cban install anything to any remote machine, from which I trigger things (particularly to linuxes).

Can I somehow start an app on my own phone, using some remote source?

Comment: Android devices can be rooted without problem, it is just him longer that simple to hide the root status because of PlayIntegrityCheck. What type of app are your talking about you want to start remotely? What have you tried so far (there are remote control apps like TeamViewer that allow UI based remote access).

Comment: @Robert The last about 10 phones were not rootable and honestly, I am really angry. I think, that is the point where our discussion ends; it is hard to say that you live in a reality where you wish to (in this case, you are a good man but can't see the reality) or you try to enforce some fake reality to others (opposite). Sad reality is that the rootability of a randomly picked phone on the market is below 10%. That is my experience, sorry.

Comment: While probably not what you wanted, but just making sure you are aware of the option of [remotely controlling your phone via adb/scrcpy](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/224310/3573) As @Robert noted, knowing what kind of app you are trying to remote start might provide alternate solutions for non-root devices. Do be aware though that custom ROMs are not dead: https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/

Answer (score 0):

Any automation app can easily perform such tasks, try [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&referrer=utm_source%3Dstackoverflow) (free) with a flowchart to start an app upon receiving a "cloud" message:

1. Flow beginning
2. [Cloud message receive](https://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/cloud_message_receive.html)
3. App start
4. (loop back to #2)

And a flowchart to send the "cloud" message:

1. Flow beginning
2. Cloud message send

Or use the online endpoint to send it from a browser.